# create custom filepath in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I need to create a fixed path for the System Drive or C: for most Windows devices.  I Need to set C: as the fixed path and build off of it with added directories.  So far my code works but wondering if there is a better way.  I set it as a string.  I know about SHGetKnownFolderPath and FOLDERID but haven't found one for just SYSTEM DRIVE.  I am using C++ 17 and visual studio for this.  This is for Windows only devices.

```
    std::string dir = "C:\\";
    fs::create_directory(dir + "_icons");
    fs::permissions(dir, fs::perms::all);
```

Comment: You could always use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` to get the folder for Windows via `FOLDERID_Windows` or the System folder via `FOLDERID_System` and extract the drive from the path it returns.

Comment: Since C++ 17. Check out [std::filesystem][1]. You don't have to rely on hard coded paths that may or may not work. 


  [1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Comment: @Vahan What part of the filesystem library provides information about what could be considered the system drive/volume in the context of what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Check the answer rturrado gave.

Comment: @Vahan I've already seen it and I"m pretty sure simply stuffing the directory in an instance of `std::filesystem::path` isn't what the OP is looking for. The goal seems to be to *"create a fixed path for the System Drive"* which isn't always `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `std::filesystem`, you could start from a `C:\` path and query its `root_directory()`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/s54obxTzn)

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    const fs::path c{ "C:\\" };
    auto icons_dir_path{ c.root_directory() / "_icons" };
    if (fs::create_directory(icons_dir_path)) {
        fs::permissions(icons_dir_path, fs::perms::all);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could follow @CaptainObvlious suggestion and:

1. Get the Windows folder installation via `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with `FOLDERID_Windows` as `KNOWNFOLDERID`.
2. Extract the drive from the path it returns (for example, via `PathGetDriveNumber`).
3. Then, let's say you got the drive in a `windows_drive` string, you could whether:

- set `std::string dir = windows_drive + ":\\";` in the code you posted, or
- set `const fs::path windows_drive_path{ windows_drive + ":\\" };` in my example above.

This should be a more robust solution as it would work no matter the drive where Windows is installed.

Comment: What if my system volume is `D:` instead of `C:`? What if my install doesn't even have a `C:` volume?

Comment: Then `fs::create_directory` would fail. I understand the OP is only interested in `C` being the system volume: *I Need to set C: as the fixed path and build off of it with added directories.*

Comment: But you're right and I could be wrong, as they also say: *I need to create a fixed path for the **System Drive** or C:*...

Comment: They're also looking at trying to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` to retrieve that path. Take a look at my original comment to the OP and consider how it applies to what they're trying to do. Might be a nice alternative in your answer.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for the suggestion. Since the OP is after a Windows specific code, I reckon this is a more robust solution.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for the feedback.  I guess it would depend on if C: is always the drive but the question of what if its a different volume would warrant a different answer.

Comment: @rturrado Thanks for the feedback.  I could probably be more specific.  I guess it would be different solutions depending on drive specific or volume specific.

Comment: I will try both suggestions from @rturrado and CaptainObvlious.  Those sound much better than what I was trying to do.  Thanks all.